# How to split an application across two eclipse projects C and C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Our code is in plain C - and requires a C complier, not C++. We have to link it with C++ code.

I am trying a simple exercise, with dummy code, not the real stuff; just two Eclipse projects, one compiled as C and not linked, and the other to be compiled as C++ and linked with the C object.

I will instantiate an object of a C++ class and call one of its methods from C (with, as pointed out by StoryTeller, the corerct C binding), and also call a plain C function from the object, as proof of concept.

How do I go about it? My problems are only with Eclipse, not with the code.

---

[Update] I mixed C++ and C into one file & the compiler was chosen based on extension: G++ for .cpp and gcc for .c

I have to rush to a meeting, then home, but will update this tomorrow.

Comment: Two Makefile projects. And write whatever you want in the makefiles...

Comment: *"I will instantiate an objetc of a C++ class and call one of its methods from C"* - without proper C binding this is doomed to fail.

Comment: Eclipse is supplying the makefiles. Whcih is where I run into problems.

Comment: In the Makefile project *you* are "supplying" them. Make sure the "generate makefile automatically" is unchecked in the build options..

Comment: Alas, I can do that for my simple demo, but not for the real project. It is dictated from on high that Eclipse generte the makefile for that.

Comment: Good luck then...

Comment: Vote to close ... with no explanation ... plus ca change ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turned out to be quite simple.

Since I want to produce only a single executable, I created a single project; a C++ project, as it happens, but …

Right click on a given directory or source file and choose Properties/Settings/Compiler and choose the language applicable compiler. For GNU, chose `g++` for C++ code and `gcc` for C code.

As a bonus, you can (but do not need to), from the Project menu, clear the “Build automatically” option. This adds new right click context menu items to each source file, to “Clean/Build selected file(s)”, which can be useful on all projects, not just mixed language.

As the question was only about configuring Eclipse, not about coding. However, if you do want to mix C and C++ in a single project, a very good starting place is [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp).